# WPF Delete button in listview mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button inside a listview to delete selected item.when i click on the button RemoveSubjectCommand is not firing. if i put the button outside the listview it is working fine. hopw this is just because of nested item. how can i solve this problem?

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AssignedSubjects}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Subjects" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="X" Command="{Binding RemoveSubjectCommand}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

View Model,

```
private ICommand removeSubjectCommand;
**
public ICommand RemoveSubjectCommand
{
    get { return removeSubjectCommand ?? (removeSubjectCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.RemoveSubject(), null)); }
}
**
private void RemoveSubject()
{ ***
}
```

If i put following code, it will work fine.

```
<ListView.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding RemoveSubjectCommand}" />
</ListView.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Hi. How you delete that row without parameter sent to command?

Comment: @Javidan, For this you use the buttons `CommandParameter`. E.g. use `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` to bind it to the DataContext of your ListViewItem, which is the item itself. Then, in your ViewModel, you can define the `DelegateCommand` to accept the parameter e.g. as `public DelegateCommand<object> RemoveSubjectCommand{ get; }` (note the `<object>` I added, it can by the way be any other type as well as long as everything remains consistent).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because DataContext of button is ListBoxItem DataContext. So you need to go to parent ListView DataContext.

one way to do that, is to give ListView a name, and to bind with element name

```
<ListView Name="lv" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AssignedSubjects}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Subjects" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="X" Command="{Binding ElementName=lv,Path=DataContext.RemoveSubjectCommand}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I believe you can skip the naming part by using binding and findancestor.

Comment: Right, findancestor is another way to do this, but since it allready exists in answer, I choose this one

Comment: I don't get it, how do we know which item to delete from the collection if no Command Parameter is being sent through the Button? There is also no binding to SelectedItem property in the ListView to the ViewModel...

Comment: well,I assume that item viewmodel have RemoveSubjectCommand command, and it know how to delete itself from the list.

Answer (score 8):

You need to bind the Command to using **[FindAncestor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx)**. Otherwise, it'll try to bind to a `RemoveSubjectCommand` using the *ListViewItem*'s datacontext, not the ViewModel's.

Try this:

```
<Button Content="X" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Path=DataContext.RemoveSubjectCommand}"  />
```

Comment: TemplateParent will not be ListView, but ListViewitem, isn't it?

Comment: Had to put `DataContext.RemoveSubjectCommand` instead of `RemoveSubjectCommand` in your answer. thanks and upvoted

Answer (score 2):

> if i put the button outside the listview it is working fine

Because `RemoveSubjectCommand` property is defined in the data context of `ListView`, not in the data context of *item*.